# Simple RegEx: I can't seem to catch the period

Tags: regex, preg-replace

**CODE:**

```
$raw = "Test List: Dist. dist Disti distributor";
$repld = preg_replace('/\b(dist(\.|i?)(ributor)?)\b/i', 'ruff', $raw);
echo $repld;
```

**Expect:**
Test List: ruff ruff ruff ruff

**Get:**
Test List: ruff. ruff ruff ruff

There's that stubborn little period after that first "ruff" that I just can't seem to figure out.
Granted, I'm no regex wiz, but I thought `\.` would be a match :)

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\b` won't match the part between `.` and . Because that's not a word boundary.

Move the `\.` past the `\b`:

```
$repld = preg_replace('/\b(disti?(ributor)?)\b\.?/i', 'ruff', $raw);
```

although of course now it matches `Distributor.` which you might not want. But then again even your original code matches `distiributor` which you might not want either.

Comment: Matching `distributor.` won't cause any problems in this case. Thanks.

Comment: Can you further clarify why it wasn't matching `.`? I'm struggling to understand the explanation.

Comment: Simplifying your regexp for the string `" Dist. "` by ignoring all the cases not used for this example, it's `/\bdist\.\b/i`. So the `\b` is matching after the `.` and before the ` ` - remember that `\b` is a zero-width pattern so it's not matching a particular character or string, it's just matching at a point between two characters.  However `\b` always matches a word boundary which means there must be either a letter before it or a letter after it; neither `.` nor ` ` is a letter. Is that any clearer?

Comment: Crystal!!  Thanks-a-bunch.